# Stuck in exercise related to proof theory and first order logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

Use the C rule and proposition 2.10 to prove $$\forall x(A(x)\to B(x)\lor C(x))\land\lnot\forall x(A(x)\to B(x)))\vdash\exists x(A(x)\land C(x))$$

[ [C rule](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA78) ]

[ [A4 rule](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA74) ]

[image]

This is what I've done so far

By hypothesis,$\forall x(A(x)\to B(x)\lor C(x))\land\lnot\forall x(A(x)\to B(x)))$, particularly $$\lnot\forall x(A(x)\to B(x)))$$ $$\implies\exists\lnot x(A(x)\to B(x)))$$

Also by hypothesis, $$\forall x(\lnot A(x)\lor B(x)\lor C(x))$$

How do I proceed from here? Should I apply C rule or A4 rule?

I don't know how to get $\exists x(A(x)\land C(x))$

Comment: The exercise is from Mendelson Logic book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-rule, exists a new constant $c$ such that $\vdash_C\neg(A(c)\rightarrow  B(c))$ and this is equivalent to $\vdash_CA(c)\wedge \neg B(c)$, so $\vdash_CA(c)$.

As hypothesis you have that $\vdash\forall x((A(x)\rightarrow B(x))\vee C(x))$. Then you can conclude that $\vdash_CC(c)$  (here I use A.4 rule on the previous statement).

Now, by $\exists$-introduction you have $\vdash_C\exists x(A(x)\wedge C(x))$. The conclution follows by proposition 2.10.

Comment: $p\lor q\to p$?

Comment: @Michelle if $q$ is false.

Comment: I don't see how you got $\vdash_CC(c)$. When you use A4 rule, then you get  $(A(c)\to B(c))\lor C(c)$? And how do you get $\vdash_CC(c)$?

Comment: In my first paragraph I get $\vdash_C \neg(A(c)\rightarrow B(c))$.

Comment: I see, and then you use MP.

Comment: @Michelle Yes, I do.